# Any Silverlight-based Thumbstick controls out there?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, controls

I'm trying to implement a simple game - I've written a dial control but having trouble writing a on-screen thumbstick in Silverlight for Windows Phone - this would be a large circle - say 150px wide with a 25px circle which when held down moves round the centre much like a real thumbstick - like the Xbox 360 controller thumbsticks.
I'm finding creating this a little tricky - if there are any examples such as a Joystick one I can shrink down for example? Been trying to create something for ages and can't seem to figure it out - the centre circle is loaded from an Image and the Larger one too so it can be customised - getting the two to be within each other centred is the easy part!

Comment: This would probably easier being done with XNA for wp7. Have you considered implementing it using XNA already? http://create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/touchthumbsticks

Comment: XNA is not an option it has to be a Silverlight application - can't use XNA as as 7.0 app - I'd found a couple of XNA examples - some of the maths for these may apply to me though - most of the logic is C# - plus I tried this example actually, was not at all what it says - you can tap anywhere, must be fixed thumbstick, like a real one.

Comment: what do you mean with "cant use XNA as a 7.0 app"? Of course you could adjust the sample to only recognize taps that are in a specified rectangle.

Comment: I suppose I could - wasn't really sure how to accomplish it, my comment was if I was creating a 7.1 app I could use it as is as you can mix XNA and Silverlight - which would make better use of your example!

Comment: Its easy. Just create a new Rectangle at the position of the thumbstick with the size you desire and use the .Contains(...) overload to check if the position of the tap is inside it and then act accordingly (update the stick, or ignore input). Done! http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.contains.aspx

Comment: @UrbanEsc I'll take another look at the example - you can put this as an answer, I will mark it as such if it helps me create a Silverlight version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, i'd suggest using XNA doing it since its considerably easier to do. With Mango you could combine XNA and Silverlight and therefore satisfy your needs for some Silverlight too.

Look at this example:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/touchthumbsticks

It shows how to easily create a thumbstick control. To restrict the area which you can touch, just create a new Rectangle at the position of the thumbstick with the size you desire and use the .Contains(...) overload to check if the position of the tap is inside it and then act accordingly (update the stick, or ignore input).

Check out the .Contains(...) function and its overloads:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.contains.aspx

I have learned that many programmers tend to stick to Silverlight for they think XNA is some kind of holy grail and is complex to program. It is not. It just needs a bit of getting used to, but you will surely enjoy the ride to XNA enlightment. I can tell, i did :) It's fun! Just trust a stranger on the internet!

If you need to stick to Silverlight and Pre-Mango, i fear i can offer nothing of value for you, and i fear you will suffer pain in trying to recreate the same functionality XNA already offers programmers for no charge.

Comment: I'm adding functionality to a Silverlight application where this is a requirement - if I could do it in XNA I would - however this example might help port it to Silverlight, but yes normally I would be fine with using the right tool for the right job